# How to determine disk I/O requirement for a particular sorting algorithm given cluster size and output buffer

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking for an answer to this question that comes from a class on data structures and algorithms. I learned about the merge sort but don't remember clusters and buffers. I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Can someone help explain or answer it?

> A file of size 1 Million clusters is
>   to be sorted using 128 input buffers
>   of one cluster size. There is an
>   output buffer of one cluster size. How
>   many Disk I/O's will be needed if the
>   balanced k-way merge sort (a
>   multi-step merge) algorithm is used?

Comment: Nice question!.  Which specific terms do you understand and which ones do you not understand?

Comment: replace 'cluster' with 'byte' and see if you can do the math for how many times through the loop you will need...

Comment: I'm not sure about the clusters and buffers. I have read about them in other computer science books, but I don't understand the relationship between them and the algorithm in the question.

Comment: A cluster is not a well defined size, but you can decide that it is 1 KiB (kibibyte - often called a kilobyte), or 1 MiB (mebibyte - megabyte), or any other convenient number.  The input buffers mean that you can read 128 clusters into input, but the output buffer (singular) means that whenever you've got one cluster's worth of output data, you have to write it out to disk.  It isn't clear to me whether your answer needs to be an algebraic expression in terms of K, or whether you can assume K = 128.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the question so well. Could it be that the answer to the question is the algebraic expression in terms of K because the size of a cluster is not well defined? But to actually solve it I would have to assume a certain size for the cluster?

Comment: Everything is specified in clusters, so specific physical units (eg block size) may not be necessary to solve this.

Comment: Not the same person as on here http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=464899 is it? :)

Answer (score 1):

It is asking about the total number of disk operations, a cluster here can be any size.

You need to know how many Disk IOs are needed per iteration of a balanced k-way merge sort.
(hint: every merge pass requires reading and writing every value in the array from and to disk once)

Then you work out how many iterations must be performed to read your data.

The total number of Disk IOs can then be calculated.